# How can I programmatically get an element from the drop-down menu on this web page?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I retrieved this HTML with a web scraper:

[image: Here is the html from the website]

I want to extract the element for the second option, `<a class="c-menuItem_link " href="/lists/members/import?id=280749">Import contacts</a>`. How can I do this? I have this code so far, but it doesn't work:

```
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dijit__FocusMixin_0"]/li[3]/span'))) 
item = elem.select_by_visible_text('option 1')
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried

Comment: I've tried using this to get the xpath and select it. elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dijit__FocusMixin_0"]/li[3]/span')))
    #item = elem.select_by_visible_text('option 1') @PedroMaia

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited your post to follow standards here - fixed some formatting, made sure a clear question is asked, fixed the tags, and [removed noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/). We still need more information from you in order to answer the question. In particular: when you use your code, what exactly goes wrong? What is the result in `item`, and how is that different from the result you want? Also: you should show the HTML as copied-and-pasted text, formatted like code - [**not**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) as an image.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was basically just asking if anyone would know based on the html to find the element of the import contacts line. Not necessarily the code in python, I'm running into errors with selenium unable to locate an element on the tag I've used.

Comment: What do you mean by extract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//*[@id='dijit__FocusMixin_2']/li[2]/a
```

A proper xpath for that element would be the above. Since it's the 2nd li in that id.

```
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id='dijit__FocusMixin_2']/li[2]/a')))
```